# Powershell - DataSet contains the number of records

Tags: sql-server, powershell, file-io

I'm seeing some odd behavior.  On my machine, PowerShell returns the recordset and I can iterate through the records no problem.  On my co-worker's machine (who has access to the file share that I need to copy the files from) is getting a record count returned instead the actual records.  I must be missing something easy.  Any idea why I'm seeing this different behavior?

```
 $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = server; Database = db; Integrated Security = True"
 $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 $SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT fileName from SomeTable"
 $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
 $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
 $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
 $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
 $Table = new-object data.datatable
 $Table = $DataSet.tables[0]
 $SqlConnection.Close() 

 function Out-FileForce {
 PARAM($path)
 PROCESS
 {
     if(Test-Path $path)
     {
         Out-File -inputObject $_ -append -filepath $path
     }
     else
     {
         new-item -force -path $path -value $_ -type file
     }
 }
 }

foreach ($Row in $Table.Rows)
{
    $fullPath = $Row.FullFilePathWithName 
    $path = "\\server\folder\"
    $newPath = "C:\newFolder\"


    $newDestination = $fullPath -replace [regex]::Escape($path), $newPath

    #Write-Output $newDestination
    #Write-Output $fullPath

    # recurse should force the creation of the folder structure
    #Copy-Item $fullPath $newDestination -recurse
    Out-FileForce $newDestination
    Copy-Item $fullPath $newDestination -force
    Write-Output $newDestination " done"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:-

$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

returns the row count if you would like that for later assign it to something:-

$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

or if you don't require it:-

[void]$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

both of the above will avoid the need to skip 1

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out a fix, I'm still not sure why.

$DataSetTableRows was causing the issue

Fixing the original script I posted.

Added this to the top:

$Table = new-object data.datatable
$Table = $DataSet.tables[0]

Then in my loop I used $Table.Rows

Comment: Your call to $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) will return number of rows. Add out-null to the call: $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | out-null